# Fill parent container

Tags: html, css, parent-child

After several hours of design battle I come to you for a hand. I am building a website for a night club as you can see.
[image: wbesite preview]

I can't get stretch the centered area (bordered by yellow color) to the bottom of the page where the footer start (the footer is the green top-bordered div). This happends because the content is not enought to fill the rest of heigh.

This is my css

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#container{
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -50px; /* as #footer height */
    min-height: 100%;
    text-align: center; 
    border: 5px solid blue;
}

#centered-container{
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    border: 5px solid yellow; 

}

#body-container{  
    border: 5px solid red; 
}

#footer, .footer{
    height: 50px;
}

#footer{
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 5px solid green;
}
```

And this is my html markup

```
<body>
    <div id="container"> <!-- BLUE BORDER -->
        <div id="centered-container"> <!-- YELLOW BORDER -->
            <div id="body-container"> <!-- RED BORDER -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer"></div> <!-- GREEN BORDER -->
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Expected behaviour:

[image]

Additional facts
 - The colored borders is just for debugging porpuses

Comment: You're setting height to both `auto` and `100%` in #container. Shouldn't you remove the `auto` property to get this behavior?

Comment: I did it, looks like there is not difference

Comment: Why don't you put a bigger height to your center-container?

Comment: @ManuelChoucino, because this will not stretch the elements where the content resides (the white area)

Comment: @manix Could you show up what you want to achive with a picture? Sorry but I am a visual:)

Comment: so you do not want the yellow border to continue on until it reach the footer? if that the case, you wont have other option then using absolute position with a fix height and width. if you could put a link where I can work on that help a lot.

Comment: @manix and you will have to change the z-index.

Comment: I will test the @irrelephant code at first. If not, I will do your customs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take out the `height: auto !important;` in `#container`. Add `height: 100%;` in `#centered-container` and `#body-container`. You can change the margins a bit to make it fit better.

The most important thing is that the path of tags from `html` down to `#body-container` must all have `height: 100%`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/NQHjc/

**Edit**

Based on the comments, I added

```
position:relative;
top:50px;
```

to `#footer`. See http://jsfiddle.net/NQHjc/3/. Note that if the text overflows the div, it will have scroll bars (using this method, it's pretty much required).

Comment: In my browser (Google Chrome) the content goes beyond the footer by quite a bit in your fiddle.

Comment: yes, I have tested the code in the web at that happen as @Codemonkey says

Comment: I have made that trick before, but it moves the footer under-visible and then the vertical scroll bar appears... By all of it I called this "the battle of 1000 days"

Comment: The scroll bar I mentioned shouldn't show up in footer but in the content div. I think you're talking about another scroll bar that I'm not seeing.

Comment: @irrelephant, the scroll bar appears to scroll down the entire page, not the footer div content

Comment: I guess that's because the window is so small on jsfiddle - and the bottom 50px is taken up by the footer. I lowered the height percentage on html and body a little: http://fiddle.jshell.net/NQHjc/7/show/

Comment: Sorry to make both of you work so hard. I really apreciate all your help. Thank you guys :)

Comment: Nhaaaaaaa we are doing it because we love it :)

Answer (score 0):

if you do not mind having the yellow border you could do this

Adding some CSS for a new element.

```
#whiteBox{
    width:100%;
    height:1250px;
}
```

And adding new element between your red border

```
    <div id="body-container"> <!-- RED BORDER -->
            <div id="whiteBox"></div>
    </div>
```

Note that I put a height of 1250px as I do not have the height of your picture.
But play with the height as I not know the exact height of your pic/element.

I would add something like that in JS

```
    window.onload = function(){
        var whiteBox = document.getElementById("whiteBox");
        whiteBox.style.height = window.innerHeight/100 * 80 + "px";
    }
```

Comment: Well, the idea of putting a fixed height is not good, because the screen resolution can change

Comment: you could use of some JS to combine the height you want.

Comment: That is an opcion also :) Now I got to make it works. Thank you som much!